# Pythonの字句解析結果を取得する方法について

Tags: python, python3

お世話になります。

[pythonのドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)によると、以下のように書かれています。

> Python で書かれたプログラムは パーザ (parser) に読み込まれます。パーザへの入力は、 字句解析器 (lexical analyzer) によって生成された一連の トークン (token) からなります。

このときの字句解析器 (lexical analyzer) によって生成された一連のトークンを取得する方法はありますでしょうか？

具体的には以下のようなコードの場合、

```py
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```

以下のような字句解析結果が取得したいと思っています。

```
"def","function","(","foo",")",":","print","(","foo",")"
```

以上、宜しくおねがいします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

標準で付属する`tokenize`モジュールはいかがですか?

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tokenize.html

Comment: `tokenize`モジュールの`generate_tokens`を使用したところ、無事に取得できました。ありがとうございました！